# Generation has thrown an exception: Vector.angle(other): zero length vectors have no valid angle Rigify Error

Tags: rigging, error, rigify

It's me again, let me get to the point. I'm having trouble rigging my creature Slugfin.I don't know where I went wrong, but the error says this:

[image]

if the image is not loading or something, it says "Generation has thrown an exception: Vector.angle(other): zero length vectors have no valid angle" I'm not an expert with rigify and stuff like this, and it's hard for me to figure this error out. I'll also add the .blend file. I'm using the latest verios

[image]

if you don't want to download the blend file, here's the rig
[image]
this error happened when I upgraded the rig's face bones.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured out that bone forehead.L.001 was in the middle when it's not supposed to be. this bone should be right here.

[image]